# Ajax php script returning include error

Tags: php, ajax

**RESOLVED** - refer to bottom of post

Hey everyone first post so I apologize in advance if the format is not so accurate; nevertheless here is my issue..

I have a simple form for adding users email to a DB. I’m utilizing ajax to submit the form and php to process (add to DB) a valid form submission.

The ajax script is sending the data correctly - I’m utilizing firebug to validate the form data is being passed along – and I’ve validated the php script specified in the ajax call is receiving the data correctly.

The problem resides in the data being passed back to the ajax success function. I have an include call in the php script to include a class for connecting to my DB, and a plethora of DB functions (running quires, setting DB tables, closing DB connection.. etc.. etc..). When the ajax success function returns the data a php ‘missing include’ error is included in the returned data.

```
Theories I have that is causing this:
```

1.) For whatever reason, the include call in the php script is being processed when the ajax success function returns the  data

2.) The include call never is processed on the server side and is acting as a returning string

Question: can an include call be used in the method I am utilizing?

Hopefully I’ve included enough information, if not please let me know what else is needed. thanks for any help. =]

Here is the code:

AJAX SCRIPT:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "xxxx/include/module/mailing_list/mailvalidation.php",
    data: formData,
      beforeSend: function(){
         //validation code for form\\
      },
      success: function(data){
        alert("successful submissio: " + data);
      }
  )};
```

PHP SCRIPT:

```
include("xxxx/library/database/class_lib_db.php");
cleanPost();
if (userInDB){
    insertUserInfo();   
    echo "You ajax post was submitted " . $_POST['first_name'] . " " . $_POST['last_name'];
} else {
    echo "Your already registred " . $_POST['first_name'] . " " . $_POST['last_name'];  
}
```

Here is the error returned in the ajax data:

> Warning: include(xxxx/library/database/class_lib_db.php)
>   [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>   in
>   /home/xxxx/public_html/xxxx/include/module/mailing_list/mailvalidation.php
>   on line 77
>
> Warning: include(xxxx/library/database/class_lib_db.php)
>   [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>   in
>   /home/xxxx/public_html/xxxx/include/module/mailing_list/mailvalidation.php
>   on line 77
>
> Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening
>   'xxxx/library/database/class_lib_db.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in
>   /home/xxxx/public_html/xxxx/include/module/mailing_list/mailvalidation.php
>   on line 77

**RESOLVED**

I had the edit the include call in the php script

before: `include("xxxx/library/database/class_lib_db.php");`

after: `include("../../../../xxxx/library/database/class_lib_db.php");`

**NOTE**: i have never had to reference my include calls with '../' before only utilizing ajax

Comment: this error means that the path `aokcdc/library/database/class_lib_db.php` doesn't exist

Comment: Hey scibuff, thanks for the reply. I am familiar with php parse error’s I’ve ran into this one a lot. However I wish it was that simple. I have validated that the include file does indeed exist. 

Before implementing ajax I submitted the form using basic jQuery submit methods and I had no problems with the include whatsoever.. any other thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the path in your include function to

```
include("../../../library/database/class_lib_db.php");
```

If you're making an ajax request to "xxxx/include/module/mailing_list/mailvalidation.php", the include statement in the PHP script is actually pointing to "xxxx/include/module/mailing_list/xxxx/library/database/class_lib_db.php"